# want to replace the text inside span of parent div

Tags: jquery

I have my html structure like

```
  <div>
   <div class="comments-title-wr clearFix">
    <span id="commentsSize" class="comments-title">Some Text</span>
    </div>

    <div id="testId">

    </div>

 </div>
```

I can retrieve `testId` and using this I want to replace text inside `<span>` tag.

I tried using

```
  $('#testId').parent().closest('.comments-title').text().replace('something else');
```

but it's not working

Comment: [`replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) is a js function which requires 2 parameters. It is a method of `String`, and it does not modify the original, it returns a new string with the replacements applied. But you don't even need this function. The problem is that you are calling the jQuery [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method with no arguments, which returns the text content of an element, but all you get is a String object, and there's no way to modify the text in the element itself. Instead, you should use a version of `text()` which takes an argument.

Comment: Thanks Tcovo for your explaintion +1 for this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want

```
$('#testId').parent().find('.comments-title').text('something else');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PdXTd/)**

```
$('#testId').prev('.comments-title-wr.clearFix').find('.comments-title').text('something else');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#testId').prev().find('span').text('HI');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#testId').prev().children('span').text('something else');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `siblings`. http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

`.comments-title-wr` and `#testId` are siblings. Somehow missed that inner span, answer updated.

```
$('#testId').siblings('.comments-title-wr').find('.comments-title').text('something else');
```